# Itō diffusion as a solution to a martingale problem

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Let

- $b,\sigma\in C_b([0,\infty)\times\mathbb R)$
- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a filtration on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$
- $B$ be an $\mathcal F$-Brownian motion on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$
- $X$ be a real-valued stochastic process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with $${\rm d}X_t=b(t,X_t){\rm d}t+\sigma(t,X_t){\rm d}B_t\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0\tag1$$

Now, let $$A_tf:=b(t,\;\cdot\;)f'+\frac12\sigma^2(t,\;\cdot\;)f''\;\;\;\text{for }f\in C^2_b(\mathbb R)$$ By the Itō formula, $$M_t^{[f]}:=f(X_t)-f(X_0)-\int_0^t(A_sf)(X_s)\:{\rm d}s=\int_0^t\sigma(s,X_s)f'(X_s)\:{\rm d}B_s\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0\tag2$$ for all $f\in C^2(\mathbb R)$ (clearly, the $A_t$ are well-defined for such $f$ too).

> I'm new to martingale problems, but if I understood the idea correctly, we're given a family $(\mathcal L_t)_{t\ge0}$ of linear operators from a subspace $\mathcal D\subseteq\left\{g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R\mid g\text{ is bounded and Borel measurable}\right\}$ to $\left\{g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R\mid g\text{ is Borel measurable}\right\}$ and say that $X$ is a solution of the $\mathcal F$-martingale problem for $(\mathcal D,(\mathcal L_t)_{t\ge0})$ iff $$N_t^{[f]}:=f(X_t)-f(X_0)-\int_0^t(\mathcal L_sf)(X_s)\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0$$ is an $\mathcal F$-martingale for all $f\in\mathcal D$.
>
> Now, in the scenario described above, I've seen that people choose the domain for the operators $A_t$ to be $C_0^2(\mathbb R)$ or even $C_0^\infty(\mathbb R)$. What's the reason for that?
>
> Clearly, the important thing is that the right-hand side of $(2)$ is a (strict) $\mathcal F$-martingale. This ensured as long as $(\sigma(t,X_t)f'(X_t))_{t\ge0}$ is square-integrable. Since $\sigma$ is bounded by definition, it should be sufficient to ensure that $f'$ is bounded too. So, isn't $C_b^2(\mathbb R)$ the more natural choice for the domain of the $A_t$?

Comment: Why would you want to assume that $\sigma$ is bounded? Everything makes perfectly sense if $\sigma$ is of linear growth (and smooth enough, e.g. Lipschitz)

Comment: @saz Just wanted to make sure that the right-hand side of $(2)$ is a strict martingale.

Comment: Yes, but that's exactly my point. If $f$ (hence $f'$) has compact support, then it suffices to know that $\sigma$ is locally bounded to ensure that the stochastic integral is a martingale.So if you are interested in studying martingale problems for coefficients which are not necessarily bounded, then it makes sense to consider $C_0^2$ or $C_0^{\infty}$ as domain.

Comment: @saz Ah, sure. I guess the point is that we're not interested in making the space of test functions as large as possible, but to make sure that this space is sufficiently large in order to derive interesting properties.

Comment: Yes, essentially that's it. (Moreover, it is often possible to pass from a domain $\mathcal{D}_1$ (e.g. $C_0^{\infty}$) to a larger domain $\mathcal{D}_2$ (e.g. twice differentiable functions vanishing at infinity) if the operator $A$ is nice enough; the idea is to approximate $g \in \mathcal{D}_2$ by a sequence $(f_n)_n \subseteq \mathcal{D}_1$ and to show that $M_t^{f_n} \to M_t^g$.)

Comment: @saz I've just noticed that I still don't see why $$\operatorname E\left[\int_0^t\left|\sigma(s,X_s)f'(X_s)\right|^2\:{\rm d}s\right]<\infty,$$ if $f'$ has compact support.

Comment: choose $r>0$ such that $\text{spt} f' \subseteq B(0,r)$; then the expectation is clearly bounded by $$t \sup_{|z| \leq r} \sup_{s \leq t} \left( |\sigma(s,z)|^2  |f'(z)|^2 \right)$$ which is finite since $\sigma$ is locally bounded.

Comment: @saz (a) How do you define "locally bounded" here? (b) Can we generalize this to continuous $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ which vanish at infinity in the sense that for all $ε>0$ there is a compact $K\subseteq\mathbb R$ with $|f(x)|<ε$ for all $x\in\mathbb R\setminus K$? We have $$\operatorname E\left[\int_0^t|σ(s,X_s)f(X_s)|^2\:{\rm d}s\right]\\\le\operatorname E\left[\int_0^t1_{\left\{\:X_s\:\in\:K\:\right\}}\sup_{x\in K}|f(x)|^2|σ(s,X_s)|^2+1_{\left\{\:X_s\:\in\:\mathbb R\setminus K\:\right\}}ε^2|σ(s,X_s)|^2\:{\rm d}s\right],$$ but don't know how I need to bound $|σ(s,X_s)|$.

Comment: locally bounded =  bounded on compact sets; this is automatically satisfied since $\sigma $ is continuous.

Comment: @saz Is it possible that you've confused $C_c^2$ (compatly supported) with $C_0^2$ (vanishing at infinity)? How do we show the square-integrability for $C_0^2$?

Comment: I was indeed talking about functions with compact support. (Not sure whether I "confused" something since you didn't explain your notation)